# Nodejs express 3 passing session object to all views

Tags: node.js, session, express

I would like to pass the session object to all my views so i don't have to pass them manually in each routes.
In the book i used to learn nodejs there was an example but for express 2 :

```
//session routes

module.exports = function(app){

  app.dynamicHelpers({
    session: function(req, res){
       return req.session;
    }
  });

  app.get(......
    res.render(....
  ....

}
```

So dynamicHelpers have been replaced. I found something on stackoverflow :

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
  });
```

I found also on express docs

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    app.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
  });
```

Anyway, in my view i have something like `<%=session.user%>` and somewhere in my route i do `req.session.user = "John"` and i always get 500 internal error : session not defined.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is that the res.locals has to be set before the app.router in the app.js file (not in routes files) !

By setting my app.js file like this :

```
app.use(express.cookieParser(hash));
app.use(express.session({
    secret: hash,
    maxAge: 3600000 
}));
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I don't even need to touch my routes files to send out the session object. In my view i can just use `<%=session.whatever%>` and it will be displayed (as only if I already set up that session variable in some of my route for ie after a login).

Comment: in my case it says `session is not define`. Any clue ?